# Writing iOS application tests that go around the app

Tags: objective-c, ios, testing, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to write some application tests for my app based on the *iPhoneUnitTests* examples on Apple dev site. Particularly I am having trouble "tapping" through elements in the app, that is, simulating the tap calling methods that make view controllers appear o disappear.

For instance I have this test:

```
- (void)testAddMeal
{
  HomeScreenController *hsCtrl = (HomeScreenController*)mainViewController;
  [hsCtrl tableView:hsCtrl.tblView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
  nutritionStrategyController = (NutritionStrategyController*)((UINavigationController*)mainViewController.modalViewController).topViewController;
  [nutritionStrategyController tableView:nutritionStrategyController.tblView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];
}
```

Which opens a first UIViewController selecting a table cell and then a second UIViewController should appear selecting a table cell in the new UIViewController.
Problem is, the test fails with this error:

```
 Unknown.m:0: error: -[NutritionStrategyTests testAddMeal] : Attempting to begin a modal transition from <UINavigationController: 0x113a2fc0> to <NewMealTrackingController: 0x9353090> while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed
```

So my question is, how do I create a test for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit tests are for testing the behavior of specific bits of code, classes, modules etc. If you want to automate user input, it is a different kind of test, you can look into the [UIAutomation instrument](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Built-InInstruments/Built-InInstruments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH6), which is dedicated to this type of testing.

> The Automation instrument, guided by your test scripts, exercises the
>   user interface elements of your application, allowing you to log the
>   results for your analysis. The Automation feature can simulate many
>   user actions supported by devices that support multitasking and run
>   iOS 4.0 or later. Your test script can run both on the iOS device and
>   in the iOS Simulator without modification.
>
> An important benefit of the Automation instrument is that you can use
>   it with other instruments to perform sophisticated tests such as
>   tracking down memory leaks and isolating causes of performance
>   problems.